# RaspberryPi MQTT Broker access via Wifi and Ethernet without interference

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, mqtt, ethernet, bridge

I would like to run an MQTT broker (Mosquitto) on a Pi2.

The Pi is connected to two networks, ethernet and wifi. Both networks are not administrated by myself.

Two independent DHCP servers in both networks.

How can I make the the broker available in both networks without interference with the network infrastructure.

Dumb question ?

Cheers

Comment: I was wondering if it is a way to go forward and run two Mosquitto broker instances which are the bridged , while each of them is listening two a different network. ??

Answer (score 0):

By default mosquitto will bind to the 0.0.0.0 address, this is a special address that represents all IP addresses of the host machine. There is no need to run 2 separate brokers, one will work just fine.

This means that the broker will be accessible from both networks. The only problem is that if the pi is getting addresses from DHCP on both interfaces then you will need to know what IP addresses have been assigned in order to access the broker from each network.

I suggest you look up a program called avahi which can be used to provide a mDNS service allowing you to refer to the pi by a `.local` domain name from both networks.

Comment: Thanks mate, I give it a go and report back.